# How to prevent visual studio 2019 from locking pdb files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a DLL and an executable setup to allow for code hot reloading. The executable reloads the DLL when there are any changes to it. It works fine when using a standalone debugger such as windbg. I would like to be able to use the visual studio debugger the same way.

The problem is that if I attempt to rebuild the project, the linker is unable to write to the pdb files because visual studio has them locked. So I get the following error:

`LINK : fatal error LNK1201: error writing to program database 'c:\Users\maxim\source\repos\transforms\x64\Debug\particles.pdb'; check for insufficient disk space, invalid path, or insufficient privilege`

How can I prevent visual studio 2019 from locking the pdb files?

Comment: Very typical behavior of aggressive anti-malware.  So disable it to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I get this when rebuilding solution X while debugging in a (second) instance of VinylStudio that uses the library built by solution X.  Could that be what's happening to you?  That's the only time I encounter this problem.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the suggestion. I tried but unfortunately the PDBs are still locked. If an anti malware was locking the file, wouldn't it also be locked for windbg though? To me it seems like it must be visual studio debugger needlessly locking the PDBs, which windbg doesn't do.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the obvious solution is to close and restart VS in order to release the lock on the file.

I suggest you could try to add the following code to the pre-build:

`if exist "$(TargetPath).locked" del "$(TargetPath).locked"`
`if exist "$(TargetPath)" if not exist "$(TargetPath).locked" move "$(TargetPath)" "$(TargetPath).locked"`

Comment: It always amuses me how utterly useless are most answers from most people at MSFT .